# Slow speed smooth motion motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm having trouble picking the right drive motor for slow smooth continuous motion combined with motion with regular precise stops. I chose a stepper motor with 0.9 degree steps which works great for quick stops but is not even close to smooth motion with low RPM. The motor also has to be quite strong to move the cargo of 3kg with 1 drive wheel with 2cm radius. I was thinking about 360 degree servos, brushless DC and brushed DC motors. The slow speeds I have in mind are a minimum of about 0.5 - 1 RPM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you need a gearbox.

Comment: +1 for a gearbox, there is no point killing your motor trying to run it outside its happy operating range. Also look at microstepping it. If you want really smooth, use a DC servo motor, but you'll need feedback for accurate speed/position control if that's important.

Comment: What do you mean by 'smooth motion'? How smooth? A stepper motor will never have smooth motion. Well, almost never; you might be able to do something clever with variable micro-stepping, but not really. Even through a gear box, there will be steps, though tiny. Maybe tiny enough that you would call them smooth. So, how smooth?

Comment: Ideally so smooth that the motion(steps) will not be seen on a video of a camera mounted on it.

Comment: Komb, that is a start. The camera has a known frame rate, and lines of resolution. So you can say you want less than, oh, 0.5 line change per frame. Now you need to know what its angular field of view will be, to get your maximum tolerable step angle.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to go with the requirement of both significant torque and smooth motion is to use a stepper motor, gear box and microstepping driver. There are definitely servo's out there that can match performance, but they will definitely be a heck of a lot more expensive and more importantly, you will need to feed in an extremely precise voltage to regulate those. Here is an idea of the kind of calculation you need to perform:

Say you have a 1080p camera with a 45-degree angle of view. Let's ignore perspective distortion for a while and assume that each pixel perfectly divides its angle of view - i.e., each pixel horizontally sees 45 degrees / 1920 pixels = 0.023 degrees. Ideally, we want horizontal wobble to be less than one pixel (although in practice up to 3 pixels may be considered acceptable for videographic purposes).

So, let's do microstepping. DRV8825 is a popular 32-microstepping driver that will be able to make your already very precise 0.9deg/step motor do 0.9/32=0.028 degree microsteps. Extremely close to our goal, but not completely there. Personally, I would definitely check this option out and try it before moving on to the next bit.

There is no (cheap) way to go smaller than 0.9 degrees, and no (cheap) way to go to more than 32 microsteps (although, microsteps aren't quite as accurate as full steps, you might get 0.033 degrees one time, and then 0.025 degrees on the next microstep). So this means you definitely have to go either gearbox or use e.g. v-groove drive. In the olden days of analogue media (LPs), this was often used to dampen the irregular motion of a driving motor and generate smoother motions on the thing that was actually driven. Also, this can give you an additional 1:3-1:5 gain you need to make those microsteps not matter anymore.